# Enable Lock Pages in Memory for SQL Server on VM

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

We have several SQL 2005 instances that are in a process of being virtulizaed and upgraded to SQL 2008 R2 running VMWare vSphere 5.1.

Our VMWare admin told me that in our org they do not over allocate memory to the guests. Per him though VMWare recommend to enable "Lock Pages in Memory" for SQL server running on virtual machines.

Does "Lock Pages in Memory" is enabled for SQL Server running on virtual machines?

Comment: I think this answers your question http://itknowledgeexchange.techtarget.com/sql-server/vmware-and-sql-and-lock-pages-in-memory/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the general consensus these days is that if you are deploying onto a modern OS such as Windows 2008 R2, and the server is dedicated to SQL Server, then lock pages in memory is generally not required. The modern OS is much better at managing memory than earlier versions, even Windows 2003. However, it'll be prudent to test both scenarios.

Comment: +1 just for mentioning testing. Validate that it is needed before turning it or anything else on. Agreement both OS and SQL Server have advanced to handle the problems that used to require this being turned on.